# end of file reached EOFError (Databasedotcom + Rails + Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, salesforce

After much frustration trying to figure it out myself, I am reaching for SO guys (you!) to help me trace this formidable error:

> Message: end of file reached EOFError Backtrace:
>   ["/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:174:in
>   `sysread_nonblock

**Background**: My App is a Rails 3 app hosted on Heroku and 100% back-end app. It uses Redis/Resque workers to process it's payload received from Salesforce using Chatter REST API.

**Trouble**: Unlike other similar errors of EOF in HTTPS/OpenSSL in Ruby, my error happens very random (since I can't yet predict when will this come up).

**Usual Suspects**: The error has been noticed quite frequently when I try to create 45 Resque workers, and try to sync data from 45 different Salesforce Chatter REST API connections all at once! It's so frequent that my processing fails 20% or more of the total and all due to this error.

**Remedy Steps**:
I am using Databasedotcom gem which uses HTTPS and follows all the required steps to connect to create a sane HTTPS connection.
So...

- Use SSL set in HTTPS - checked
- URI Encode - checked
- Ruby 1.9.3 - checked
- HTTP read timeout is set to 900 (15 minutes)
- I retry this EOF error MAX of 30 times after sleeping 30 seconds before each retry!
  Still, it fails some of the data.

Any help here please?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Would you mind sharing what you ended up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that Salesforce might not like so many connections at once from a single source and you are blocked by an DDOS-preventer?

Also, setting those long timeouts is quite useless. If the connection fails, drop it and reschedule a new one yourself. That is what Resque does fine, it will add up those waiting times if it keeps having problems...

Comment: Thanks Hugo, for DDOS at Salesforce cue! But I could not understand how can I "If the connection fails, drop it and reschedule a new one yourself." do this?

Comment: If you put making the connection in the Resque task, and tell Resque the action failed (when it does, of course), Resque will reschedule the task itself, and then of course a new connection attempt will be made.